# Create new column of cleaned string data with Python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` with some user input (it's supposed to just be a plain email address), along with some other values, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

df = pd.DataFrame({'input': ['Captain Jean-Luc Picard <picard@starfleet.com>','deanna.troi@starfleet.com','data@starfleet.com','William Riker <riker@starfleet.com>'],'val_1':[1.5,3.6,2.4,2.9],'val_2':[7.3,-2.5,3.4,1.5]})
```

Due to a bug, the input sometimes has the user's name as well as brackets around the email address; this needs to be fixed before continuing with the analysis.

To move forward, I want to create a new column that has cleaned versions of the emails: if the email contains `names/brackets` then remove those, else just give the already correct email.

There are [numerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23132227/python-pandas-extracting-hyphenated-words-from-cells-with-phrases) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22975121/shift-ragged-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-to-clean-data-with-partial-string-search) of [cleaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682044/pandas-dataframe-remove-unwanted-parts-from-strings-in-a-column) [string data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22703494/find-string-pattern-match-in-pandas-dataframe-and-return-matched-strin) with `Python/pandas`, but I've yet to find successfully implement any of these suggestions. Here are a few examples of what I've tried:

```
# as noted in pandas docs, turns all non-matching strings into NaN
df['cleaned'] = df['input'].str.extract('<(.*)>')

# AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute 'contains'
df['cleaned'] = df['input'].apply(lambda x: str.extract('<(.*)>') if str.contains('<(.*)>') else x)

# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
df['cleaned'] = df[df['input'].str.contains('<(.*)>')].str.extract('<(.*)>')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `np.where` to use the `str.extract` for those rows that contain the embedded email, for the else condition just return the 'input' value:

```
In [63]:

df['cleaned'] = np.where(df['input'].str.contains('<'), df['input'].str.extract('<(.*)>'), df['input'])

df

Out[63]:
                                            input  val_1  val_2  \
0  Captain Jean-Luc Picard <picard@starfleet.com>    1.5    7.3   
1                       deanna.troi@starfleet.com    3.6   -2.5   
2                              data@starfleet.com    2.4    3.4   
3             William Riker <riker@starfleet.com>    2.9    1.5   

                     cleaned  
0       picard@starfleet.com  
1  deanna.troi@starfleet.com  
2         data@starfleet.com  
3        riker@starfleet.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regular expressions:

```
import re
rex = re.compile(r'<(.*)>')
def fix(s):
    m = rex.search(s)
    if m is None:
        return s
    else:
        return m.groups()[0]
fixed = df['input'].apply(fix)
```